# Android: Updating the UI from an adapter inside a While Loop

Tags: multithreading, while-loop, android

I'm using a GridView to display a list of words in a 4-column table.  The getView method of my custom adapter checks the width of the word and shrinks it if it doesn't fit.  It does this using a recursive check that keeps scaling the text down *until* it fits.

```
private void shrinkText(final TextView wv, final String word) {
    wv.setTextSize(defaultTextSize);
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (wv.getWidth()>0 && wv.getPaint().measureText(word) > wv.getWidth()) {
                Logg.d("word too big. Shrink from " + wv.getTextSize()/density + " to " + (wv.getTextSize()/density-1.0f));
                wv.setTextSize(wv.getTextSize() / density - 1.0f);
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Because I'm using a while loop, I am using a new thread to protect against ANR in the unlikely event of an infinite loop. Here's the weird thing: *sometimes* it works great.  And then *sometimes* I get the following error:

```
09-26 14:25:31.389    6427-7765/com.myapp.debug E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-7789
    Process: com.myapp.debug, PID: 6427
    android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

I tried putting the setTextSize inside a runOnUiThread statement, but I can't get it to work inside the adapter.  Ultimately I just want this to work.  I think my options are:

1. Keep the while loop in the UI thread and somehow safeguard it (how?)
2. Move the setTextSize call to the UI thread (how?)
3. Something else?

Thanks for your help!

**UPDATE**: based on Rustam's answer, I used wv.post to write to the UI. However the need to use the while loop meant that setTextSize had to be done in the same thread as the while condition itself.  I switched from evaluating the TextView.getTextSize to the Paint.getTextSize, since I could set the Paint's text size without impacting the UI, and therefore inside the offshoot thread.  Jerry-rigged, but it seems to work.

```
private void shrinkText(final TextView wv, final String word) {
    wv.setTextSize(defaultTextSize);
    final Paint mPaint = new Paint(wv.getPaint());
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (wv.getWidth()>0 && mPaint.measureText(word) > wv.getWidth()) {
                Logg.d("word too big. Shrink from " + mPaint.getTextSize()/density + " to " + (mPaint.getTextSize()/density-1.0f));
                mPaint.setTextSize(mPaint.getTextSize() - 1.0f);
            }
            if (wv.getWidth()>0 && wv.getPaint().measureText(word) > wv.getWidth()) {
                wv.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Logg.d(word + " final size=" + mPaint.getTextSize() / density);
                        wv.setTextSize(mPaint.getTextSize() / density);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**try to update like this:**

```
private void shrinkText(final TextView wv, final String word) {
    wv.setTextSize(defaultTextSize);
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
                while (wv.getWidth()>0 && wv.getPaint().measureText(word) > wv.getWidth()) {
                Logg.d("word too big. Shrink from " + wv.getTextSize()/density + " to " + (wv.getTextSize()/density-1.0f));
                wv.post(new Runnable() {
                   public void run() {
                      wv.setTextSize(wv.getTextSize() / density - 1.0f);
                   }
               });
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Comment: Just tried that... It seems that the setTextSize needs to be in the same thread as the while condition.  It stopped crashing, but it also doesn't iterate - just keeps rerunning to change from 14 to 13 and then for some reason disappears off the screen altogether.

Comment: I think I solved the problem.  For sure I can't use the wv.post method inside the while loop, since the while condition is impacted by the setTextSize.  What I ended up doing was making a copy of the Paint object in the TextView and evaluating that - it didn't require me to write to the UI.  Then after the while loop completed, I used that Paint object to set the TextSize property of the TextView inside a post method.